# App freezes when playing MediaPlayer from URL

Tags: android, web-services, android-mediaplayer

I'm at a loss because I don't see any errors in Logcat.  This is what I see:

> 

```
05-11 09:15:54.267 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-11 09:15:54.447 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/ContextImpl: Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.action.URL dat=http://72.13.86.83:6626 } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:533 com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.SomafmActivity$350.onClick:25957 android.view.View.performClick:5156 
05-11 09:15:54.557 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/Streaming Radio: debug: Creating service
05-11 09:15:54.557 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/Streaming Radio: Playing from URL/path: http://72.13.86.83:6626
05-11 09:15:54.567 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/MediaPlayer: Need to enable context aware info
05-11 09:15:54.567 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
05-11 09:15:54.567 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer: constructor
05-11 09:15:54.577 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer: setListener
05-11 09:15:54.577 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
05-11 09:15:54.577 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
05-11 09:15:54.577 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
05-11 09:15:54.597 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture
05-11 09:15:54.597 14753-14753/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync
05-11 09:15:54.597 14753-14766/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val=  Samsung SM-G900V stagefright/Beyonce/1.1.9 (Linux;Android 5.0)
05-11 09:15:54.597 14753-14770/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-11 09:15:54.607 14753-14770/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-11 09:15:54.607 14753-15104/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 42001(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(49KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 107MB/123MB, paused 4.713ms total 95.583ms
05-11 09:15:54.667 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System: Ignoring header Accept because its value was null.
05-11 09:15:54.667 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-11 09:15:54.677 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-11 09:16:57.707 14753-15115/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-11 09:16:57.717 14753-15115/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-11 09:16:57.867 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System: Ignoring header Accept because its value was null.
05-11 09:16:57.867 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-11 09:16:57.877 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-11 09:18:00.907 14753-14766/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-11 09:18:00.907 14753-14766/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /72.13.86.83 (port 6626): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1194)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:295)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.IcyStreamMeta.retreiveMetadata(IcyStreamMeta.java:95)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.IcyStreamMeta.refreshMeta(IcyStreamMeta.java:85)
05-11 09:18:01.067 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro.SomafmActivity$MetadataTask1$2.run(SomafmActivity.java:871)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
05-11 09:18:01.077 14753-15101/com.LudwigAppDesign.streamingradioplayerpro W/System.err:    ... 13 more
```

My MediaPlayer works fine as long as the URL is valid, but for those URLs that have expired, the whole app freezes and I need to hit the Home button to reset.
If someone can help me understand what's happening I would really appreciate it.

Comment: So where's your code?

Comment: Try to use a thread or a service to play the stream.

Comment: share codes...................